# HighStock 2 panes with different php queries

Tags: php, highcharts

I did a Highstock Compare multiple series it works since I have different sql query for different table record.

I want to do a Highstock 2 panes charts and notice the demo http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume getjson data is a string of array eg.[1196035200000,24.80,25.32,24.62,24.65,326438434] .

I have been working on it but to no avail. Is there an multiple select sql statement to retrieve [table1date,table1value,table2date,table2value] or can it been done using multiple sql query

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your data, then parse it to adapt to correct format and use in the highcharts.